# How to get multiple counts in one query for one field?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

So what i'm trying to do is to get multiple counts of one field depending on a min max value.
Collection holds something like

```
{name:'hi',price:100},
{name:'hi',price:134},
{name:'hi',price:500}
```

What i want to get is for example the count of items that are between price 100-200, 200-300, 300-400, 400-500.

Is there a way to do this in mongoDB with one query? Is there a way to get the query without knowing min max?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple Counts with single query in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52088666/multiple-counts-with-single-query-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [`.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) here with the [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) ternary operator to determine the grouping id withing [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/):

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "price": { "$gte": 100, "$lte" 500 }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "$cond": [
                { "$lte": [ "$price", 200 ] },
                "100-200",
                { "$cond": [
                    { "$lte": [ "$price", 300 ] },
                    "200-300",
                    { "$cond": [
                        { "$lte": [ "$price", 400 ] },
                        "300-400",
                        "400-500"
                    ]}
                ]}
            ]
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

As a "ternary" `if/then/else` the [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) will evaluate the expression in the first argument "if" and then either return the second argument "then" where `true` or the third "else" where `false`.

The cascading logic means that you "nest" each ternary operation inside the `false` assertion till you reach an eventual result.

With the grouping `_id` value provided by conditions, you then just use [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) with an argument of `1` to "count" the matches in the group.

This gives you a response on the sample as:

```js
{ "_id": "100-200", "count": 2 }
{ "_id": "400-500", "count": 1 }
```

The [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) is making sure that all results are in the "ranges" that wil be tested. If you exclude that then you likely want a last [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) "else" condition to return another value if the `"price"` was outside of an expected "range".

If you are looking to return "each" range, then you are better off inspecting the result and inserting a `0` count entry for every range that is not returned.

Comment: What if i don't know the min and max and i want to get 5 values between the min and max. Example min is 1000 and max is 5000. Can i automatically make a query that would get count in between those numbers?

Comment: @Marcio Please read. I stated exactly that case in the answer. Just return the "last" `$cond` "else" condition with an "Unknown". Nothing is going to "generate" the ranges for you if that is what you are asking. You need to specify each condition to `$cond`. The `$match` as noted is just a "optimization", and not required.